# Hacer un arreglo C compuesto por arreglos A y B sin repetir sus numeros en java

Tags: java, array, condiciones

No logro eliminar los numeros repetidos del arreglo C, el arreglo C esta armado desde los arreglos A y B, creo que la logica del while es incorrecta pero aun no logro resolverlo

```
    while (i < 5) {
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            c[j] = a[i + k];
            j++;
        }
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            c[j] = b[i + k];
            j++;
        }
        i += 5;
    }

    while (i < 10) {
        if(a[i] != b[i]){
            sinRepetidos[i]= a[i] - b[i]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(sinRepetidos[i] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Y ¿cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow. Aquí no estamos en clase así que te recomiendo que no expongas las preguntas como una tarea, puesto que hacerle las tareas a los demás está bastante mal visto por aquí. Te recomiendo que expongas los problemas concretos con los que te encuentres. Para más información puedes leer [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sobre cómo elaborar una pregunta correctamente para no recibir votos negativos y evitar que la pregunta acabe cerrada. Un saludo!

Comment: perdón, no es mi intención que me hagan la tarea, gran parte esta hecho, solo que no entiendo porque no funciona mi while :/ reformularé la pregunta, gracias por tu comentario

Comment: ¿Y no sería más sencillo empezar con el array A, elemento por elemento, metiéndolo en C, comprobando uno a uno si el que vas a meter no está ya metido, y cuando termines con A, hacer lo mismo con B? Al terminar, C tendría los elementos de A y B no repetidos.

Answer (score 2):

analicemos tu logica...

```
while (i < 5) {
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        c[j] = a[i + k];
        j++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        c[j] = b[i + k];
        j++;
    }
    i += 5;
}
```

Aca estas haciendo un ciclo de nada, porque el while solo se ejecuta una vez, porque cuando llega a `i += 5;` entonces i vale 5 y `while (i < 5) {` es falso.. entonces ese while no hace nada...

Luego de eso, pasas cada elemento de a (con el sin sentido de hacer a[i + k], donde i vale siempre cero) a c, usando como posicion j.. lo cual no esta mal, pero nunca revisas duplicados...

Luego, tiras todo tu codigo a la basura, y probas los duplicados

```
while (i < 10) {
    if(a[i] != b[i]){
        sinRepetidos[i]= a[i] - b[i]);
    }
}
```

pero otra vez.. a y b tenian 5 elementos (como antes en k?) o tienen 10?

mas alla de eso, solo comparas repetidos entre los items ubicados en la misma posicion en a y b... pero que pasa si a[1] no es igual a b[1] pero si igual a b[2]????

eso, no lo comprobas nunca.

Tu comprobacion es mucho mas simple, si solo pasas los items de a al nuevo array, y luego de eso, comprobas el b que queres ingresar, y si no existe, lo agregas...

Algo estilo (en pseudocodigo)

```
//primero copiamos todo el array a al array sinrepetidos
//luego nos fijamos lo de b
for(i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    int item = b[i];
    bool repe = false;
    for (k = 0; k < a.length(); k++) {
        if (a[k] == item) {
            repe = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (repe) {
        //agrego
        a[maximo] = item
    }
}
```